# How to get the container ID from docker-py

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerpy

I'm trying to check whether a docker container is up or not using filter of docker-py module. However able to check whether it is up or down.
For reference :

```
def checkDockerContainerStatus( container):
    client = docker.from_env()
    cli = docker.APIClient()
    if client.containers.list(filters={'name': container}):
        response = client.containers.list(filters={'name': container})
        return 'Up'
    else:
        return 'Down'

checkDockerContainerStatus('app-container')
```

and I got response as `[<Container: eb42d23b6f>]`
How to retrieve the container id from this response inorder to check it is log .

I tried response['container'] , but it didn't work out. May I know to get the result as my requirement

Comment: It's a list/array of containers (or container objects) not a dict. So you've to loop over it to access each container object.

Comment: There's information on the [Container object](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#container-objects) properties in the docker-py documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The a lot of id's is confusing in docker.

You can read about types of id's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52819711/1573395).

When you understand what is short form and long form of container id your code can be something like:

```py
import docker

def checkDockerContainerStatus( container):
    client = docker.from_env()
    #cli = docker.APIClient()
    if client.containers.list(filters={'name': container}):
        response = client.containers.list(filters={'name': container})
        return str(response[0].id)[:12]
    else:
        return None

running_id = checkDockerContainerStatus('app-container')

if running_id is not None:
    print(f"Found! {running_id}")
else:
    print("Container app-container is not found")
```

Also I would recommend to use [docker SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead docker-py.

Your code wont run on docker-py and run properly on [docker SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).