# Is it possible to re-create or re-deploy docker container with same container ID?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I am storing container ID in my database, based on that I regularly check if my container is still running or has stopped using 'Docker Inspect' I update this info in my database.

The above method is fine if I only want to update the status but if someone wants to change the env. variables and use the docker run command to create the container then a new container ID gets generated.

So my question is if it is possible to generate the new docker container with the container Id it had previously?

Comment: Could you base this on container *name* instead (i.e. `docker run --name [...]`).

Comment: unfortunately no, because in my Database only container ID is being stored, but i can store container name in my Database too, is it possible to inspect a docker container based on container name in JAVA ?

Comment: Related: [How the docker container id is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012659/how-the-docker-container-id-is-generated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no option to "manually" set a UUID when you run a container. This is something that the Docker Daemon takes care of.

> ### [Container identification](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification)
>
> The operator can identify a container in three ways:
>
> ```
> | Identifier type       |                              Example value                        |
> |===========================================================================================|
> | UUID long identifier  | "f78375b1c487e03c9438c729345e54db9d20cfa2ac1fc3494b6eb60872e74778"|
> | UUID short identifier | "f78375b1c487"                                                    |
> | Name                  | "evil_ptolemy"                                                    |
> ```
>
> **The UUID identifiers come from the Docker daemon.** If you do not assign a container name with the `--name` option, then the daemon generates a random string name for you. Defining a `name` can be a handy way to add meaning to a container. If you specify a `name`, you can use it when referencing the container within a Docker network. This works for both background and foreground Docker containers.

Comment: in my java code, I am using DockerClient , which has a function to inspect a container using container ID, there is no such function for container Name :/

Comment: I'm sure there will be a way to programmatically take the `name` value of your container with java. I'd post a new question for that though...

Comment: Ya i am thinking to pass the name instead of ID inside that function and see if that works, otherwise I will post a new question.

Comment: If you are using the docker client from [github.com/spotify/docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client), it seems easy... `final ContainerInfo info = docker.inspectContainer(id);`